# How do you call this data structure?

Tags: categorical-data, dataset, terminology

I have some data which can be summarised similarly to a matrix. Var1 and Var2 are both categorical and e.g. the value for Var1==0.1 and Var2==0.2 is 0.347581.

[image]

**How do you call this data structure?** I know that this is not panel data. I want to be able to research properly and find ways to analyse it.

Answer (score 0):

From a purely software perspective, it's a **pivot table**.
Stats-wise, I would call it a **cross-tabulation**, or a **contingency table**; it's just not totalled or normalized in any obvious way.

Comment: did you realise the categories are numerical values (in example double values)? Is the answer still same? (var1 is 0.1 in example)?

Comment: Contingency tables with specific values of the variable as labels aren't terribly shocking. You could relabel the sides to VarN = Xn instead of doing it in two levels, it's just a waste of ink.

Comment: I mean Var1 is consisting of 0.1 0.3 0.4 etc and these values (0.1, 0.3 and 0.4) are double values. Is your answer same?

Comment: Why would that even matter?

Comment: in example if they were labels like car names, I cannot sort them, but if they are numerical values, I can.

Comment: *Pivot table* may be an appropriate term but *contingency table* is not. None of the rows and columns sum to 100%.

Comment: Yeah, I've been a bit reluctant to use the term because of that, but there are few better options on the stats terminology side for the OP to look up that I'm aware of. If we're being 100% honest, this is just data dumped into a matrix format.

Comment: @jkm these data are similar to my calculations which took approximately 80'000 cpu-hour seismic analysis of a structure. I am trying to perform statistical analysis on it. Also there is a third variable like Var3. I just hided the data and used random numbers in the matrix. But, I am not sure it is pivot table.

Comment: I agree with @jkm comment, this could easily be regular data in a strange matrix representation. I think the name of the data structure is irrelevant, what matters is the aim of the analysis. Alper: you have this data, Var1, Var2, Var3, etc., what are you trying to do with it? What research questions are you trying to answer?

Comment: @– E L M I guess I have my problem's answer, if you sort all Var1 and Var2 in a combination like (0.1,0.2) (0.1,0.4) (0.1,0.6) (0.1,0.8) (0.3,0.2) (0.3,0.4) (0.3,0.6) (0.3,0.8) etc you have a new (NewVar1,NewVar2) list, the data in the matrix (Var3 Var4 etc) were the thing I want to evaluate according to some criteria. I solved my question for myself. I used NewVar1 and NewVar2 as x and y axis data to plot on coordinate system. My question is solved for myself. What should I do with this question?